# Why don't unordered containers provide an interface for defining minimum load factor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to understand why hash table (unordered containers such as unordered_map or unordered_set) don't provide an interface for querying or setting minimum load factor.

Say c is a unordered_set, I can use

```
c.max_load_factor()
```

for querying

and

```
c.max_load_factor(val)
```

for setting.

Why doesn't C++11 provide an interface for querying min_load_factor? Are there implementation details, which would explain?

Also, C++ STL by Josuttis, mentions that:

The minimum load factor, which is used to force rehashing when the number of elements in the container shrinks cannot be influenced.

Comment: At a guess it's so that removing elements doesn't have to allocate memory and cannot fail (maybe unless a destructor throws, in which case you blame the element type rather than the container). I don't know whether that's the actual reason, though, there might be another stronger one.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I would say it's consistent with a number of other containers: neither `vector` nor `deque` shrink automatically.

Comment: What would a minimum load factor mean? How small it get before its re-sizes?

Comment: @andre: yes, i would say the minimum size before the hash re-hashes.

Comment: @MatthieuM: yes, possibly for the same reason? Or in the case of `vector` because there's also a capacity to respect.

Comment: There is the property that unordered_map has that all iterators (except the one to element being deleted) are valid after delete. Not sure it would be possible to keep this, if the map rehashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load factor on an `unordered_map` affects the probability of collision in the hash table. For example,the probability of two elements being located in the same bucket. The container uses the value of `max_load_factor` as the threshold that forces an increase in the number of buckets and thus causing a rehash.

There is no such thing as a user-controllable minimum load factor since it should respect the number of elements already in the container.